# Is there a way resolve design time pseudo-errors or make the IDE ignore them?

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio-2012, datagrid

I have a DataGrid from the WPF Extended Toolkit with several columns similar to the following:

```
 <xcdg:Column Title="Description" FieldName="Description" Visible="{Binding Source={x:Reference filterDescription}, Path=IsChecked, Converter={StaticResource FilterVisibility}}" />
```

The problem is that each of these columns shows a design time error of "Object Reference not set to an instance of an object" for the Visibility property.  Intellisense sees the Visibility property just fine.  Everything is functional so it doesn't really hurt anything however I'm up to 26 of these psuedo-errors and it sometimes makes finding real issues a pain.

Is there anyway to either make Visual Studio 2012 Shut up about these errors, or someway to convince the IDE that this property that it actually intellisense's is fine?  Am I missing some special design time reference?

Comment: +1 for asking something that's been driving me crazy too!!

Comment: https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedbackdetail/view/859967/vs20132-u2-rc-design-time-errors-in-xaml-build-ok

Comment: I too am hoping for a solution but a quick search found the link I posted as a possible bug they are looking at fixing in a future VS release. I wonder if the 2014 CTP release has this fixed?

Comment: is your converter handling null?

Answer (score 1):

The prothe value for null.
Anyway, the best way to solve this kind of problems is to attach Visual Studio to Visual Studio :) (I mean debugger).

1. Open the second instance of VS, then open your current project, and click on `Tools -> Attach To Process` then select `XDescProc.exe` process.
2. Click on `Debug -> Exceptions` and check the field right after `Common Language Runtime Exceptions` in `Thrown` column
3. Click `Reload designer` button on the first instance of VS.

Good luck!

Comment: I actually removed the converter altogether just in case it was causing the problem.  Even just setting Visible="true" gives the same error.  I'm intrigued by the steps you outlined though, I'm going to Give them a shot.  I will report back what I find.